# How to find and update subdocument within array based on parent property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to find a subdocument which is inside an array, based on its own user_id property and its parent's my_id property

These are the schemas I have for my model (Conversation):

```
var listSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: Number,
    property: Boolean,
});

var conversationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    my_id: Number,
    list: [listSchema]
});
```

After browsing through mongoose's documentation and some similar questions here on SO, I've tried the following (which seems to me like that it should work):

```
Conversation.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "my_id": 8, "list.user_id": 16 },
    { 
        "$set": {
            "list.$.property": false
        }
    },
    function(err, doc) {
        console.error("Error:", err);
        console.log("Doc:", doc);
    }
);
```

But it gives me this output and the documents are not being updated at all:

```
Error: null
Doc: null
```

What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured out what was going on:

I was saving the user_id property as a String to MongoDB so I tried changing this part of the query to:

```
"list.user_id": "16"
```

instead of:

```
"list.user_id": 16
```

Still didn't work, but then I figured out that I was defining user_id as Number in listSchema so I changed that to String:

```
var listSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: String,
    property: Boolean,
});
```

And now it works, it doesn't matter if I use "16" or 16 in the query, I think that mongoose will try to find a String now instead of a Number like it was doing before